# Failed to show `` (UTF-16 character) in wxWidgets (C++)

Tags: c++, c++17, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets with Visual Studio 2022 (C++) to develop Windows application. I wish to display  in the window, but as I tried using various fonts with the following code:

```
std::string fonts_name[8] = {"Calibri Light", "Calibri", "Cambria Math", "Cambria", "Candara Light", "Candara", "Consolas", "DFKai-SB"};
// ...
stat_txt_test = new wxStaticText*[8];
for (long long i = 0; i != 8; ++i) {
    stat_txt_test[i] = new wxStaticText(this, (long long)1000 + i, "", wxPoint(i * 15, i * 15), wxSize(10, 10), wxTE_READONLY);
    stat_txt_test[i]->SetFont(fonts[i]);
}
```

I only got [image: screenshot].

However, if I use `"a"` (ascii character) instead, the result is [image], which is as expected.

Now I am guessing that UTF-16 does not work well in my code. However, Chinese characters worked very well. **[This](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D465) is the unicode of .**

**How should I modify my code in order to get this job done?**

#### My attempts

`"\x1D465"` does not work and I got the following message and failure to build:

> `error C2022: '119909': too big for character`
> `"\xD835\xDC65"` does not work (just a wild guess to use two characters to represent this character).

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `"\x1D465"` obviously doesn't work because it's specifying the raw hex values. Unicode escapes are `\uXXXX` or `\UXXXXXXXX`

Comment: https://github.com/gammasoft71/Examples_wxWidgets/blob/3958bc084d1d581fd977a6ab9385af3d5b1b7cb4/src/HelloWorlds/HelloWorldEmoticons/HelloWorldEmoticons.cpp#L21

Comment: I'm not familiar with *wxWidgets* but aren't you constructing a `wxString` with a `const char*` literal?

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you! `wxT("\U0001D465")` or `L"\U0001D465"` (the same) worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in the [wxWidget's documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_unicode.html), the correct way would be as shown below:

```
//---------------------------------------vvvvvvvvv---->changed to u instead of x
label = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, L"\u0078");
```

or

```
label = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, L"\U0001D465");
```